# join xml structure with table in sql server 2005

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

```
<C1003Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <LTV>-1</LTV>
      <CLTV>-1</CLTV>
      <bIncludeSpouse>false</bIncludeSpouse>
      <bNotIncludeSpouse>false</bNotIncludeSpouse>
      <BorrowerCreditScore>
        <Experian />
        <TransUnion />
        <Equifax />
      </BorrowerCreditScore>
      <CoBorrowerCreditScore>
        <Experian />
        <TransUnion />
        <Equifax />
      </CoBorrowerCreditScore>
      <SubFinancing>
        <FirstOrSecondMortgage>-1</FirstOrSecondMortgage>
        <OtherMortgage>-1</OtherMortgage>
      </SubFinancing>
      <MortgageType>
        <strLoanApplied>01</strLoanApplied>
        <dLoanAmount>-1</dLoanAmount>
        <dInterestRate>-1</dInterestRate>
        <nNumberofMonths>360</nNumberofMonths>
        <strAmortizationType>05</strAmortizationType>
        <dGPMRate>-1</dGPMRate>
        <strLoanPosition>1</strLoanPosition>
        <dPurchasePrice>-1</dPurchasePrice>
        <dAppraisedValue>-1</dAppraisedValue>
        <dTotalLoanAmt>-1</dTotalLoanAmt>
        <dMIPorFF>-1</dMIPorFF>
        <dQualRate>-1</dQualRate>
        <nDueIn>360</nDueIn>
        <dMonthlyPmt>-1</dMonthlyPmt>
      </MortgageType>
      <PropertyInfo>
        <strAddress />
        <strCity />
        <strState />
        <strZip />
        <strCounty />
        <Warrantable>true</Warrantable>
        <strLoanPurpose>16</strLoanPurpose>
        <dCashout>-1</dCashout>
        <strPropertyWillBe>1</strPropertyWillBe>
        <dGrossRent>-1</dGrossRent>
        <dOccupRent>-1</dOccupRent>
        <nPeriod>-1</nPeriod>
        <dConstructionYearLotAcquired>-1</dConstructionYearLotAcquired>
        <dConstructionAmountExistingLiens>-1</dConstructionAmountExistingLiens>
        <dConstructionCostofImprovements>-1</dConstructionCostofImprovements>
        <dConstructionOriginalCost>-1</dConstructionOriginalCost>
        <dConstructionValueofLot>-1</dConstructionValueofLot>
        <dConstructionTotalValue>-1</dConstructionTotalValue>
        <dRefinanceYearAcquired>-1</dRefinanceYearAcquired>
        <dRefinanceAmountExistingLiens>-1</dRefinanceAmountExistingLiens>
        <dRefinanceOriginalCost>-1</dRefinanceOriginalCost>
        <dRefinanceCostofImprovements>-1</dRefinanceCostofImprovements>
      </PropertyInfo>
      <BorrowerInfo>
        <strFirstName>MARTIN</strFirstName>
        <strMidName />
        <strLastName>TESTCO</strLastName>
        <strSocSecNo>000-06-0914</strSocSecNo>
        <strHomePhone />
        <strCell />
        <strEmail />
        <strDOB />
        <strMaritalStatus>Married</strMaritalStatus>
        <strCitizenship>US Citizen</strCitizenship>
        <bPresentAddressOwnt>false</bPresentAddressOwnt>
        <bPresentAddressRent>false</bPresentAddressRent>
        <strPresentAddressStreet>4527 COWBOY LN</strPresentAddressStreet>
        <strPresentAddressCity>Santa Ana</strPresentAddressCity>
        <strPresentAddressState>CA</strPresentAddressState>
        <strPresentAddressZip>92702</strPresentAddressZip>
        <bMailingSameAsPresent>false</bMailingSameAsPresent>
        <bFormerAddressOwn>false</bFormerAddressOwn>
        <bFormerAddressRent>false</bFormerAddressRent>
      </BorrowerInfo>
      <bSameAsBorrower>false</bSameAsBorrower>
      <CoBorrowerInfo>
        <strFirstName />
        <strMidName />
        <strLastName />
        <strSocSecNo />
        <strHomePhone />
        <strCell />
        <strEmail />
        <strDOB />
        <strMaritalStatus>Married</strMaritalStatus>
        <strCitizenship>US Citizen</strCitizenship>
        <bPresentAddressOwnt>false</bPresentAddressOwnt>
        <bPresentAddressRent>false</bPresentAddressRent>
        <bMailingSameAsPresent>false</bMailingSameAsPresent>
        <bFormerAddressOwn>false</bFormerAddressOwn>
        <bFormerAddressRent>false</bFormerAddressRent>
      </CoBorrowerInfo>
      <BoEmploymentInfo>
        <bSelfEmployed>false</bSelfEmployed>
        <strWorkPhone />
      </BoEmploymentInfo>
      <CoEmploymentInfo>
        <bSelfEmployed>false</bSelfEmployed>
        <strWorkPhone />
      </CoEmploymentInfo>
      <BoFormerEmpInfo>
        <CFormerEmploymentInformation>
          <bSelfEmployed>false</bSelfEmployed>
        </CFormerEmploymentInformation>
      </BoFormerEmpInfo>
      <CoFormerEmpInfo>
        <CFormerEmploymentInformation>
          <bSelfEmployed>false</bSelfEmployed>
        </CFormerEmploymentInformation>
      </CoFormerEmpInfo>
      <SREO>
        <CSchedule>
          <dMarketValue>-1</dMarketValue>
          <dAmtOfMtg>-1</dAmtOfMtg>
          <dGrossRent>-1</dGrossRent>
          <dMtgPayment>-1</dMtgPayment>
          <dInsTaxMisc>-1</dInsTaxMisc>
          <dNetRent>-1</dNetRent>
        </CSchedule>
      </SREO>
      <GrossMonthlyIncome>
        <dBorrowerBaseIncome>-1</dBorrowerBaseIncome>
        <dBorrowerOvertime>-1</dBorrowerOvertime>
        <dBorrowerBonuses>-1</dBorrowerBonuses>
        <dBorrowerCommissions>-1</dBorrowerCommissions>
        <dBorrowerDividends>-1</dBorrowerDividends>
        <dBorrowerNetRentalIncome>-1</dBorrowerNetRentalIncome>
        <dBorrowerOtherIncome>-1</dBorrowerOtherIncome>
        <dBorrowerOtherIncome1>-1</dBorrowerOtherIncome1>
        <dBorrowerTotal>-1</dBorrowerTotal>
        <dCoBorrowerBaseIncome>-1</dCoBorrowerBaseIncome>
        <dCoBorrowerOvertime>-1</dCoBorrowerOvertime>
        <dCoBorrowerBonuses>-1</dCoBorrowerBonuses>
        <dCoBorrowerCommissions>-1</dCoBorrowerCommissions>
        <dCoBorrowerDividends>-1</dCoBorrowerDividends>
        <dCoBorrowerNetRentalIncome>-1</dCoBorrowerNetRentalIncome>
        <dCoBorrowerOtherIncome>-1</dCoBorrowerOtherIncome>
        <dCoBorrowerOtherIncome1>-1</dCoBorrowerOtherIncome1>
        <dCoBorrowerTotal>-1</dCoBorrowerTotal>
        <dTotalBaseIncome>-1</dTotalBaseIncome>
        <dTotalOvertime>-1</dTotalOvertime>
        <dTotalBonuses>-1</dTotalBonuses>
        <dTotalCommissions>-1</dTotalCommissions>
        <dTotalDividends>-1</dTotalDividends>
        <dTotalNetRentalIncome>-1</dTotalNetRentalIncome>
        <dTotalOtherIncome>-1</dTotalOtherIncome>
        <dTotalOtherIncome1>-1</dTotalOtherIncome1>
        <dTotalTotal>-1</dTotalTotal>
        <dOtherIncome1>-1</dOtherIncome1>
        <dOtherIncome2>-1</dOtherIncome2>
        <dOtherIncome3>-1</dOtherIncome3>
        <dPresentRent>-1</dPresentRent>
        <dPresentFirsMortgage>-1</dPresentFirsMortgage>
        <dPresentOtherFinancing>-1</dPresentOtherFinancing>
        <dPresentHazardInsurance>-1</dPresentHazardInsurance>
        <dPresentRealEstateTaxes>-1</dPresentRealEstateTaxes>
        <dPresentMortgageInsurance>-1</dPresentMortgageInsurance>
        <dPresentHomeownerAssociationDues>-1</dPresentHomeownerAssociationDues>
        <dPresentOtherExpenses>-1</dPresentOtherExpenses>
        <dPresentTotal>-1</dPresentTotal>
        <dProposedFirsMortgage>-1</dProposedFirsMortgage>
        <dProposedOtherFinancing>-1</dProposedOtherFinancing>
        <dProposedHazardInsurance>-1</dProposedHazardInsurance>
        <dProposedRealEstateTaxes>-1</dProposedRealEstateTaxes>
        <dProposedMortgageInsurance>-1</dProposedMortgageInsurance>
        <dProposedHomeownerAssociationDues>-1</dProposedHomeownerAssociationDues>
        <dProposedOtherExpenses>-1</dProposedOtherExpenses>
        <dProposedTotal>-1</dProposedTotal>
      </GrossMonthlyIncome>
      <ScheduleOfRealEstate>
        <bCurrentResidence>false</bCurrentResidence>
        <bBubjectProperty>false</bBubjectProperty>
        <dPresentMarketValue>-1</dPresentMarketValue>
        <dMortgageLiens>-1</dMortgageLiens>
        <dMortgagePayments>-1</dMortgagePayments>
        <dMaintTaxesIns>-1</dMaintTaxesIns>
        <dGrossRentalIncome>-1</dGrossRentalIncome>
        <dNetRentalIncome>-1</dNetRentalIncome>
        <bAddAnotherProperty>false</bAddAnotherProperty>
        <bCurrentResidence1>false</bCurrentResidence1>
        <bBubjectProperty1>false</bBubjectProperty1>
        <dPresentMarketValue1>-1</dPresentMarketValue1>
        <dMortgageLiens1>-1</dMortgageLiens1>
        <dMortgagePayments1>-1</dMortgagePayments1>
        <dMaintTaxesIns1>-1</dMaintTaxesIns1>
        <dGrossRentalIncome1>-1</dGrossRentalIncome1>
        <dNetRentalIncome1>-1</dNetRentalIncome1>
        <bAddAnotherProperty1>false</bAddAnotherProperty1>
        <bCurrentResidence2>false</bCurrentResidence2>
        <bBubjectProperty2>false</bBubjectProperty2>
        <dPresentMarketValue2>-1</dPresentMarketValue2>
        <dMortgageLiens2>-1</dMortgageLiens2>
        <dMortgagePayments2>-1</dMortgagePayments2>
        <dMaintTaxesIns2>-1</dMaintTaxesIns2>
        <dGrossRentalIncome2>-1</dGrossRentalIncome2>
        <dNetRentalIncome2>-1</dNetRentalIncome2>
        <bAddAnotherProperty2>false</bAddAnotherProperty2>
        <dTotalPresentMarketValue>-1</dTotalPresentMarketValue>
        <dTotalMortgageLiens>-1</dTotalMortgageLiens>
        <dTotalGrossRentalIncome>-1</dTotalGrossRentalIncome>
        <dRentalIncome>-1</dRentalIncome>
        <dTotalMortgagePayments>-1</dTotalMortgagePayments>
        <dTotalMaintTaxesIns>-1</dTotalMaintTaxesIns>
        <dTotalreportedNetRentalIncome>-1</dTotalreportedNetRentalIncome>
        <dEffectiveNetRentalIncome>-1</dEffectiveNetRentalIncome>
      </ScheduleOfRealEstate>
      <AssetsInfo>
        <bJointly>false</bJointly>
        <dAmountOfDeposit>-1</dAmountOfDeposit>
        <dAmountOfDeposit1>-1</dAmountOfDeposit1>
        <dTotalBankDeposits>-1</dTotalBankDeposits>
        <dMarketValueOfRealEstate>-1</dMarketValueOfRealEstate>
        <dVestedInterest>-1</dVestedInterest>
        <dNetWorthOfBusiness>-1</dNetWorthOfBusiness>
        <dLifeInsuranceFaceAmount>-1</dLifeInsuranceFaceAmount>
        <dLifeInsuranceMarketValue>-1</dLifeInsuranceMarketValue>
        <dSubtotalLiquidAssets>-1</dSubtotalLiquidAssets>
        <dAutomobileOwned1>-1</dAutomobileOwned1>
        <dAutomobileOwned2>-1</dAutomobileOwned2>
        <dAutomobileOwned3>-1</dAutomobileOwned3>
        <dStocksAndBond1>-1</dStocksAndBond1>
        <dStocksAndBond2>-1</dStocksAndBond2>
        <dStocksAndBond3>-1</dStocksAndBond3>
        <dOtherAssest1>-1</dOtherAssest1>
        <dOtherAssest2>-1</dOtherAssest2>
        <dOtherAssest3>-1</dOtherAssest3>
        <dOtherAssest4>-1</dOtherAssest4>
        <dTotalAssest>-1</dTotalAssest>
        <dAlimony>-1</dAlimony>
        <dJobRelated1>-1</dJobRelated1>
        <dJobRelated2>-1</dJobRelated2>
        <dNetWorth>0</dNetWorth>
        <dBalanceTotal>-1</dBalanceTotal>
        <dPaymentTotal>-1</dPaymentTotal>
        <dMarketValue>-1</dMarketValue>
        <dMtgAmount>-1</dMtgAmount>
        <dCrossRentInc>-1</dCrossRentInc>
        <dMtgPayment>-1</dMtgPayment>
        <dInsTaxExp>-1</dInsTaxExp>
        <dNetRent>-1</dNetRent>
        <dAccountNumber1>-1</dAccountNumber1>
        <dAccountNumber2>-1</dAccountNumber2>
      </AssetsInfo>
      <BankDeposite>
        <CBankDeposite>
          <dBankValue>-1</dBankValue>
        </CBankDeposite>
      </BankDeposite>
      <Liabilities>
        <CLiabilities>
          <bResubordinated>false</bResubordinated>
          <bOmitted>false</bOmitted>
          <dLiabilitiesBalance>-1</dLiabilitiesBalance>
          <dLiabilitiesPayment>-1</dLiabilitiesPayment>
          <dLiabilitiesMosLeft>-1</dLiabilitiesMosLeft>
          <bLiabilitiesPaidOff>false</bLiabilitiesPaidOff>
        </CLiabilities>
      </Liabilities>
      <TransactionDetails>
        <dPurchasePrice>-1</dPurchasePrice>
        <dAlterations>-1</dAlterations>
        <dLand>-1</dLand>
        <dRefinance>-1</dRefinance>
        <dPrepaidItems>-1</dPrepaidItems>
        <dClosingCosts>-1</dClosingCosts>
        <dPMIandMIP>-1</dPMIandMIP>
        <dDiscount>-1</dDiscount>
        <dTotalCosts>-1</dTotalCosts>
        <dSubordinateFinancing>-1</dSubordinateFinancing>
        <dPaidBySeller>-1</dPaidBySeller>
        <dOtherCredits>-1</dOtherCredits>
        <dOtherCredits1>-1</dOtherCredits1>
        <dOtherCredits2>-1</dOtherCredits2>
        <dOtherCredits3>-1</dOtherCredits3>
        <dClosingCost>-1</dClosingCost>
        <dLoanAmount>-1</dLoanAmount>
        <dPMIandMIPFinanced>-1</dPMIandMIPFinanced>
        <dLoanAmountAutomatic>-1</dLoanAmountAutomatic>
        <dCashFromToBorrower>0</dCashFromToBorrower>
      </TransactionDetails>
      <Declarations />
      <MonitoringPurposes>
        <bBorrowerFurnish>false</bBorrowerFurnish>
        <bCoBorrowerFurnish>false</bCoBorrowerFurnish>
      </MonitoringPurposes>
      <Other>
        <TSBalloon>false</TSBalloon>
        <TSBiweekly>false</TSBiweekly>
        <TSCommunityLending>false</TSCommunityLending>
      </Other>
      <RequestForAppraisal>
        <Appraiser />
        <Lender />
        <From />
        <EscrowCompany />
        <TitleCompany />
        <ListingAgent />
        <SellingAgent />
        <AppraisalType>
          <Full>false</Full>
          <ExteriorOnly>false</ExteriorOnly>
          <MarketRentAnalysis>false</MarketRentAnalysis>
          <LandAppraisal>false</LandAppraisal>
        </AppraisalType>
        <EstimateOfValue>
          <AsIs>false</AsIs>
          <AsCompleted>false</AsCompleted>
        </EstimateOfValue>
        <FannieMae>
          <FM1004>false</FM1004>
          <FM1004C>false</FM1004C>
          <FM1004D>false</FM1004D>
          <FM1007>false</FM1007>
          <FM1025>false</FM1025>
          <FM1073>false</FM1073>
          <FM1075>false</FM1075>
          <FM2000>false</FM2000>
          <FM2000A>false</FM2000A>
          <FM2055>false</FM2055>
          <FM216>false</FM216>
          <FM2075>false</FM2075>
          <FM2090>false</FM2090>
          <FM2095>false</FM2095>
          <FMNA>false</FMNA>
        </FannieMae>
        <VeteransAdministration>
          <VA1805>false</VA1805>
          <VA8712>false</VA8712>
        </VeteransAdministration>
        <AppraisalCost>-1</AppraisalCost>
        <PaymentMethod>
          <COD>true</COD>
          <CreditCard>false</CreditCard>
          <InvoiceClient>false</InvoiceClient>
          <Bill>false</Bill>
          <Other>false</Other>
        </PaymentMethod>
      </RequestForAppraisal>
      <RequestForTitle>
        <Seller />
        <InsuredLenderMortgage />
        <Attachment>
          <PriorTitlePolicy>false</PriorTitlePolicy>
          <WarrantyDeed>false</WarrantyDeed>
          <TitleInsRequirements>false</TitleInsRequirements>
          <Survey>false</Survey>
          <Contract>false</Contract>
        </Attachment>
        <MailAway>false</MailAway>
      </RequestForTitle>
      <RequestForHazard>
        <MinReplacementCost>-1</MinReplacementCost>
      </RequestForHazard>
      <SollenAdditionalInfo>
        <LockPrice>-1</LockPrice>
        <LockPeriod>21</LockPeriod>
        <PrepayPenalty>No</PrepayPenalty>
        <BorrowerEmp>W-2</BorrowerEmp>
        <IRSForm>Yes</IRSForm>
      </SollenAdditionalInfo>
      <FloodReport>
        <IsInFloodArea>false</IsInFloodArea>
      </FloodReport>
    </C1003Data>
```

In this XML structure, I use the following query for select firstname and lastname:

```
SELECT
   a.b.value('(strFirstName)[1]', 'Varchar(50)') FirstName,
   a.b.value('(./strLastName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)') LastName
FROM dbo.FormData
CROSS APPLY C1003.nodes('//BorrowerInfo') a(b)
```

It executes correctly. Now I need to join this structure with other table which also has first name and last name. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure we you even bother with a `.nodes()` call since you only have one `<BorrowerInfo>` node - to join the first name and last name against a relational table, use something like:

```
;WITH XmlData As
(
    SELECT 
       FirstName = C1003.value('(/C1003Data/BorrowerInfo/FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       LastName = C1003.value('(/C1003Data/BorrowerInfo/LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
       dbo.FormData
    WHERE
        .... -- possibly define a WHERE clause here!
)
SELECT
    t.a, t.b, t.c  -- whatever columns you need here .....
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable t
INNER JOIN
    XmlData x ON t.FirstName = x.FirstName AND t.LastName = x.LastName
```